# Is a set that contains itself always logically incoherent?

Tags: epistemology, ontology, set-theory

## This is an ontological engineering question, please treat it that way.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_engineering
I am examining this question from the point of view of ontological engineering.
Russell's paradox is based on forming a set of all sets that do not contain themselves.

Within the last few years it occurred to me that set membership could be defined through ontological engineering to inherit from a generic base class: total_containment. Both physical and conceptual total containment would inherit from the base class.

In order for a thing to totally contain another thing the outer boundary of the contained thing must be entirely contained within the outer boundary of the container. This forces the container to be somewhat larger than the contained and thus makes it impossible for anything to totally contain itself.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please take a quick moment to take the tour (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or see general help (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. (http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. Additional clarification at (https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Questions of engineered ontologies and their implementation on computers should be asked in AI SE. https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, there are versions of set theory that allow such sets, see [non-well-founded set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory), e.g. Aczel corresponds sets to [accessible pointed directed graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom).

Comment: @Conifold Indeed; see also the sources mentioned in the "more substantively" part of my answer (it's worth noting that we can find such theories of *very low* consistency strength).

Comment: Why is this on hold? Non well-founded sets are a thing, the OP's reputation notwithstanding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory

Comment: @user4894 This question is pushing the OP's personal viewpoint (see also the comments below my answer where the OP argues that my answer, which develops the quite correct point in your comment, is irrelevant to their question). That already makes it opinion based; one might decide to give the question the benefit of the doubt (at least temporarily) but previous interactions with the OP have convinced me that there is no reason to do so. (Note that I do agree with you that the *title question* is perfectly fine; when I initially gave this question the BotD it was that that I was responding to.)

Comment: My objection is not that question per se is not relevant to the ontology of set theory but that the context of the question seems to be more interested in the object-oriented approach of engineering a computer-based ontology. The context seems to ask implicitly for affirmation that a metadata model could have such an architecture. I don't consider it normative, but just that a better home for it might be in AI. Reference to classes, primitive and derived knowledge and property inheritance, though derived from philosophy and set theory, would get a more knowledgable response. You got answers.

Comment: @JD It seems to me that there is a natural preexisting way that every element of the set of knowledge inherently fits together. A set that totally contains itself has no coherent way to fit into this natural knowledge ontology in the same way that the details of a square circle cannot be fully elaborated.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT I'd suggest you are conceptualzing knowledge with the containment metaphor, and that an analysis of the nature of propositional knowledge would show that the metaphor is a limit. Propositions can be inherently recursive, and that this violates the extensionality of space shows the limitation of mapping an ontological primitive of "meaning bearer"
 to an ontological primitive of physical space such as "container". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphor

Comment: @JD It doesn't really seem metaphorical at all. Sets do literally have members. These members are literally contained within these sets. Physical containment and conceptual containment are two different aspects of the exactly same thing. Since no physical thing can possibly totally contain itself, then no conceptual thing can totally contain itself when we refer to containment as one single thing.

Comment: You're confusing figurative and conceptual metaphors. Concepts don't literally contain anything anymore than memory cells are actual cells in a building. Neither are literally containers. Here's a construct that contains itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Comment: @JD I disagree. There is physical containment and conceptual containment that apply the exact same concept of containment to two different types of objects. In each of these two cases there is a defined boundary and there are the notions of inside and outside this defined boundary. Nothing conceptual or physical can be totally inside its own outer boundary because the boundary itself can not be contained within itself. This is demonstrated when one tries to draw a Venn diagram. Two circles of identical size makes it impossible for one of these circles to be contained within the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101388/discussion-between-j-d-and-pl-olcott).

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT: it may be worthwhile for those interested in answering this question to familiarize themselves with the OP's earlier posts throughout the stackexchange site - e.g. [here (now deleted)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64876/can-incompleteness-be-eliminated-by-redefining-the-notion-of-a-formal-system?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435499/do-any-sets-contain-themselves), or [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/63700/why-do-we-need-model-theory-to-express-semantics/63743#63743) - under this and related usernames. I did not check the username ahead of time, or I would not have answered; that said, I've decided to leave this answer up since it may be useful for other readers.*

*Re: my decision to vote to close after answering while not deleting my own answer, see [this meta discussion](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5013/answering-then-voting-to-close).*

## No, it's not.

(Unless you interpret "logically incoherent" with "incompatible with my own intuitions about sets," which is - to put it mildly - questionable).

---

First of all, the claim that regularity in ZF resolves Russell's paradox is a (very common) mistake. *Adding* an axiom never *removes* inconsistencies; any contradiction present in the weaker system remains present in the stronger system. Rather, what saves ZF from Russell's paradox is the *removal* of full comprehension - mere [separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom) only lets us prove that for every set A the set R_A:={x in A: x not in x} exists, but that's no paradox at all (the Russell argument shows that R_A is not an element of A, but so what?).

What the axiom of regularity does is imply that the **class** of non-self-containing sets is the entire universe. But that's a separate issue.

---

More substantively, there are set theories which permit (indeed, require) self-containing sets which are known to be consistent relative to theories we have high degrees of faith in. For example, the theory ZFC - Regularity + [Aczel's antifoundation axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom) is consistent if ZFC is, and proves the existence of self-containing sets.

For more dramatic examples see e.g. [this article of Holmes](https://math.boisestate.edu/%7Eholmes/holmes/separticle.pdf), especially section 6.2 - the point is that there are set theories which imply the existence of self-containing sets with extremely weak consistency strength.

And in a more normative direction, various authors have actively argued for such theories; it may be worth reading their arguments (see e.g. the sources in [the Stanford Encyclopedia article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/)).

---

All that you've argued is that self-containing sets contradict *one particular* intuition about sets. But nobody has a monopoly on that notion. Unless you interpret "logically incoherent" as "in contrast with my own beliefs," there's no issue here.

Comment: What I am proposing logically follows form the semantic base meaning of the term "total containment". Within the goal of deriving the natural pre-existing ontology for the set of all knowledge we are not free to overload one concept with another incompatible concept. We can at most further elaborate the base concept by providing more details.

Comment: When we take the common meaning of {total containment} as our base concept we can only add and not override its base meaning. When its base meaning stipulates any totally contained object must have its outer boundary inside of the containers outer boundary then anything totally containing itself becomes a logical impossibility.

Comment: @PL_OLCOTT You asked "Is a set that contains itself always logically incoherent?," not "Is a set that contains itself incompatible with the following approach to sets?" If you wanted to ask the second question, then ask it; otherwise, the answer above is correct.

Comment: I was asking the question from an ontological engineering point of view. I did not make this quite clear enough initially. Your answer was clearly not from an ontological engineering point of view. When we look at things from an ontological engineering point of view it is a matter of how concepts are constructed from their constituent parts. When we try to construct the concept of a set containing itself on the basis of the generic concept of total containment the pieces do not seem to fit together.

Comment: Certainly it is very common practice to allow terms of the art to overload and thus override the conventional meanings of these terms. When we disallow this practice and try to construct the concept of a set containing itself from the generic concept of total containment it really seems that we fail. How can anything be totally inside itself?